# What does character "^" do in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a formula in Excel like this `D484/(1+$J$6)^B484`.

What is `^` doing in this formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an *exponentation* operator, with a precedence higher than multiplication or division; that is, the cell is evaluated as

```
D484/((1+$J$6)^B484)
```

`(1+$J$6)` is raised to the `B484`th *power*.

It *looks* like an discounting (i.e. present value) formula to me, where `$J$6` is an interest rate with annual compounding, `B484` a time in years, and `D484` a cash amount.

Answer (score 3):

It means "to the power of" ie 10^2 is 10 squared ie 10 * 10 so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To answer your title (rather than just the question within):

> What does character “^” do in Excel?

It can mean a variety of things depending on context

1) It can designate an exponent operation, such as x to the power of y ("x^y"). This is the meaning of `"^"` in your formula;

2) For 64-bit Office VBA editions only, it can designate that an operand value should be treated as a LongLong, 64-bit integer value data type (for example, "234^");

3) With scraping it can be part of a CSS selector and designates *"starts with"*. In the below, the `^` says pick all `img` tagged elements, within element with id `"images"`, that have an `src` element which starts with `'img/'`.

[image: CSS selector]